# "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.com/. Origin http://.ru is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I saw a lot of posts about it but there is no solution for me. It's just error. What should i do? I Have script on my web-server and i can't get access to url.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
xmlhttp.send();    
}
document.write(httpGet("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
```

Comment: please try looking into something called jsonP

Comment: Yes, but I need to get html text. Not Json

Comment: for cross-domain-requests , I believe you need to have jsonP or use this header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');